# Auto read and send email variable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to read an email and then send a value in that email into another page. I've successful to read email and detect subject and date of that email. After read that incoming email, I need to send that value into another php page whoch in that page I can do background process.

Here's the code to read email

```
include "connect.php";
$mailbox = imap_open("{mail.xxxxx.com:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "username", "password"); //Note 1
$count = imap_num_msg($mailbox);

$headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $count);
$sub = $headers->subject;
$time = $headers->date;
$pieces = explode("://",$sub);

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE web='$pieces[1]' AND date='$time'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($check);
if($time != $date['date']) {
//code to send parameter here
echo "enter";
} else {
echo "no";
}
```

I need to send an email subject and email date into another php page. What ways can be used ? Is that with javascript, ajax or what ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What you are doing is not safe!  You are likely open to SQL injection attacks.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Why this is not safe ?. Read email or send it to another page that can be SQL injection attacks ?

Comment: You are using raw data from an e-mail and not escaping any data when inserting that into your database.  Someone could send a message to you with SQL commands.